# How to build tensorflow lite c++ shared library for armeabi-v7a?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I am trying to build c++ shared library of tflite for armeabi-v7a. Has anyone tried it? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

General instructions for building TensorFlow Lite from source, for an Android target, can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/README.md).

The [tensorflow-lite.aar target](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/BUILD#L18) includes the TensorFlow Lite native shared library, and this .aar can be dropped into your usual Android build pipeline (e.g., Android Studio or gradle). Alternatively, you can build the [native shared library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/BUILD#L172) directly via:

```
bazel build --cxxopt='--std=c++11' -c opt --config=android_arm tensorflow/contrib/lite/java:libtensorflowlite_jni
```

Comment: This does not work, the resulting .so has no references to `tflite::Interpreter` and so on.